# What are the "non-extended attributes" (as opposed to "extended attributes") in Linux?

Tags: linux

Linux has what is called "extended attributes", but I am wondering what are the  "non-extended attributes", I am assuming they are things like the file permissions, file owner, file dates, etc.

Am I correct? and is there a documentation that lists all of the "non-extended attributes"?

Comment: All those attributes that are not name:value pair should be considered non-extended, notice this is API level, the actual data structure storage form can be very complex and filesystem dependent. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html, all things that are not able to read/write using xatrr API should be considered non-extended.

Answer (score 1):

The basic attributes are those that you can retrieve with the [stat(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) system call.

```
       struct stat {
           dev_t     st_dev;         /* ID of device containing file */
           ino_t     st_ino;         /* Inode number */
           mode_t    st_mode;        /* File type and mode */
           nlink_t   st_nlink;       /* Number of hard links */
           uid_t     st_uid;         /* User ID of owner */
           gid_t     st_gid;         /* Group ID of owner */
           dev_t     st_rdev;        /* Device ID (if special file) */
           off_t     st_size;        /* Total size, in bytes */
           blksize_t st_blksize;     /* Block size for filesystem I/O */
           blkcnt_t  st_blocks;      /* Number of 512B blocks allocated */

           /* Since Linux 2.6, the kernel supports nanosecond
              precision for the following timestamp fields.
              For the details before Linux 2.6, see NOTES. */

           struct timespec st_atim;  /* Time of last access */
           struct timespec st_mtim;  /* Time of last modification */
           struct timespec st_ctim;  /* Time of last status change */

       #define st_atime st_atim.tv_sec      /* Backward compatibility */
       #define st_mtime st_mtim.tv_sec
       #define st_ctime st_ctim.tv_sec
       };
```

Comment: unlike `statx`, it seems unable to get file attributes, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_iflags.2.html This seems not be the extended attributes, they're not name: value pairs